# Showing docker container log in aws ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have trouble showing log from my docker container in ecs.

> What I did:
>   1) ssh into an ec2 instance of the cluster.
>   2) docker logs my service

Then this message is showing up:

```
FATA[0000] Error executing 'logs': Failed to get log configuration: Container 'my-container': Must specify log driver as awslogs
```

**What I am trying to do is to show log in the console.**
**What I don't understand is that for some container, the command docker logs works fine.**

Answer (score 2):

open docker daemon file in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add log driver:

```
  {
     "log-driver": "awslogs"
  }
```

and restart docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: The command systemctl is not found, I am running on Amazon linux AMI.

Comment: @superphung sorry. try this : `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: I tried sudo service docker restart and then manually docker start each services. But when i tried docker logs a container i got this message: Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading

Comment: this usually requires a log group and region ([specified here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/)) but this is the answer that got me down that path

Answer (score 1):

You should choose the docker log driver to `json-log` while creating the task definition revision in ECS, If you want to see the docker logs with `docker logs container-id` command. you will get the container id from the docker ps command.

But if you want to push docker logs to cloudwatch logs then you have to choose `aws-logs` as docker log driver.

For some containers, it might work fine because those have docker log driver as json-file set in their task definition.

How to create a task definition?
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html

Do let me know if you are still facing the issue.